# Git commits appear with git log but not with git log <filepath>

Tags: git, git-log

When I run `git log --name-status` I can see my files that were modified in my commits.
However, when I run `git log myfilename` specifying one of the filenames that appeared in the previous command some commits are not listed.

Why could this be?

Comment: And with `git log --follow -- myfilename`?

Comment: And `--full-history`?

Comment: The commits appear when I use `--follow` or `--full-history`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The commits appear when I use `--follow` or `--full-history`.

That means your file has been :

- renamed (`--follow`)
- involved with merged branches (`--full-history`, since the default mode prunes some side branches if the end result is the same (i.e. merging branches with the same content)

See the blog post "[Git – Full History](http://blogs.isostech.com/git/git-full-history/)" from [Scott Smith](http://blogs.isostech.com/author/scott_smith/):

> a series of changes can cancel each other out which means that history is “simplified” by default.
>   Those changes that cancel each other out will appear to have never existed without using the “`–full-history`” switch.

[Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/340993/ben) confirms the second case [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366171/git-commits-appear-with-git-log-but-not-with-git-log-filepath/29370387#comment46924011_29370387):

> what happened was first the changes that I made on my branch were merged back to the main line.
>   **Afterwards the same changes were duplicated on another branch by another developer and then merged back in to the main line**.

Comment: The file in question hasn't been renamed but it has been involved with merged branches.

Comment: @Ben ok, that is why I added the link to the blog post, which illustrates that issue.

Comment: Ok, what happened was first the changes that I made on my branch were merged back to the main line. Afterwards the same changes were duplicated on another branch by another developer and then merged back in to the main line.

Comment: @Ben Good catch. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.